# web link extractor function explained?

Tags: python

i have been working on an online course which walks us through the creation of a function which crawls a string for web links. You can see the function below:

```
page = 'This is a <a href="http://udacity.com">Link!</a>.This is a <a href="http://egg.com">Link!</a>.This is a <a href="http://bread.com">Link!</a>'

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find("<a href=")
    if start_link == -1:
        return None, 0
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote +1)
    url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
    return url, end_quote

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print url
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

print_all_links(page)
```

However, i still don't understand how it works together? To, me, it looks like two separate functions. I understand how the first function -- (`print_all_links(page)` -- works, but what i am stuck on is how the second part takes information from the first function?

Specifically, what is the `while` and `if` statement under the `while` doing? I don't understand what they are checking for, or how they and getting the information from the first function.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind Regards. :)

Answer (score 2):

#### `get_next_target(page)`

This finds the string `"<a href="` in the page. It then extracts the link following the next `"` up to yet another `"` and returns that link and the position of the `"` the link ended at.

#### `print_all_links(page)`

This takes links from the page via `get_next_target` as long as possible (`while True: ...`). It fetches the next link and the ending position. If the link text is `None` (i.e. no link could be found), it stops (that is the `else` clause). Otherwise (`if url:`), it prints the link address and replaces the page text by everything *after* the link that was just extracted so that the next link can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

your whole algorithm comes down to this part of the code:

```
page.find("<a href=")
```

i.e. the [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) function:

> `string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

Basically, what your algorithm does is:

- iterate over the string to find the next `"<a href="` starting from the start or the previous position

cf:

```
start_link = page.find("<a href=")
```

- find the part between quotes starting just after the found position

cf:

```
start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
end_quote = page.find('"', start_quote +1)
url = page[start_quote + 1: end_quote]
```

- return that part, the target url, and the current position of the `""<a href="` from `get_next_target`
- if the `get_next_target` function does not return a valid value, it then breaks the loop
- otherwise it prints it out and starts over with the new position

---

*N.B.*: an alternative and simpler way to capture all the links within your string is to use a regular expression:

```
>>> page = 'This is a <a href="http://udacity.com">Link!</a>.This is a <a href="http://egg.com">Link!</a>.This is a <a href="http://bread.com">Link!</a>'
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'<a href="([^"]+)">')
>>> r.findall(page)
['http://udacity.com', 'http://egg.com', 'http://bread.com']
```

to understand what the regex means, look at the following:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[And run through it live](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TEzPaGV0UD_IstS_)

basically, you can see it looks up (thanks to `findall`) and captures everything that starts with `<a href="` and ends with `">` – `<a href="…">`, and captures everything in between (literally, any character that is not a `"`) – `([^"]+)`.

---

to show how much of an improvement this is, here's a small benchmark I made for fun, over 1000000, and removing the `print` function from `print_all_links`:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: print_all_links(page), number=1000000)
6.7976109981536865
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'<a href="([^"]+)">')
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=lambda: r.findall(page), number=1000000)
1.823470115661621
>>> 6.7976109981536865/1.823470115661621
3.7278433793729966
```

almost 4x faster using a regex :-)

HTH ;-)